# Qt: No border on buttons making them non-clickable?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to set a style to a button so that it has no border, but it seems the lack of border then makes the button non-clickable. Is there a better way of getting no border?

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton(todo, self)
button.move(0, i * 32)
button.setFixedSize(200,32)
button.setCheckable(True)
button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: rgb(75, 75, 75); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: left; font-size: 12pt; border: none;}")
```

Comment: I tried using `setFlat(True)` but this made the background color of the buttons bright grey. I'm also having the problem of the `checked` state having that same bright grey back ground.

Comment: Try a _very_ light border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1). It's hackish, but it might work. I had this issue too and just gave it up without realizing it was the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: WHOOPS, just noticed this is a Question regarding Qt/Python (and not Qt/C++), well maybe my answer helps anyways..

Just tried it, and it works for me...
Here is the code i used:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("i am toggleable", &w);
    button->setFixedSize(200,32);
    button->setCheckable(true);
    button->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton { \
        background: rgb(75, 75, 75);\
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\
        text-align: left;\
        font-size: 12pt;\
        border: none;\
    }\
        QPushButton:checked {\
        background: rgb(105, 105, 105);\
    }\
    ");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

notice i added a additional CSS rule for checked buttons, so it gets visible if a Button is checked or not. Are you sure your buttons dont work, or could it be, that you just dont see that they are working ?!

EDIT2: If it doesnt work for you, you could just use `setFlat(True)`, and use additional CSS rules to fix the colors (like in my example).

Comment: Adding the `QPushButton:checked` rule worked fine. Thank you!